# How does one show a subspace of Hilbert space is closed

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am self-studying some analysis and am trying to plug a hole in my understanding of subsets of Hilbert space. Is there a typical/general method for proving that a subspace of an infinite dimensional Hilbert space is closed? As a concrete example, I would like to show that the following is a Hilbert space:

Let H be the function space $L^2(-a,a)$, $a>0$, equipped with the integral inner product $\langle h_1,h_2
\rangle=\int_{-a}^a h_1h_2dx$ and the added condition that $h(x)=h(-x)$. Please show that $H$ is a Hilbert space.

I understand that we can use a Cauchy sequence argument to show that if a subspace of a Hilbert space is closed then is is also complete and hence a Hilbert space. In the above example, how would one typically show that $H$ is closed?

thanks

Comment: You can show that the subspace is equal to its closure. Take a convergent sequence of elements in the subspace, and show that the limit must also belong to the subspace.

Comment: Convergence of a sequence in $L^{2}(-a,a)$ implies almost everywhere convergence of  subsequence. This implies that your set is closed.

Answer (score 2):

If $\varphi :X\to Y$ is a continuous function between two metric spaces, then for every $y\in Y,$ the set $$\{ x\in X\,:\, \varphi(x)=y\}$$ is closed in $X.$ In particular for any bounded (equivalently continuous) linear operator $T:L^2(-a,a)\to L^2(-a,a)$ the subspace $\ker T$ is closed. Consider $$(Tf)(x)=f(x)-f(-x)$$ Then $T$ is bounded. Therefore $$\ker T=\{h\,:\, h(x)=h(-x)\}$$ is a closed subspace of $L^2(-a,a),$ hence it is a Hilbert space.

Comment: Maybe you could add (for more clarity) to your explanation that every bounded linear operator between Hilbert spaces is continuous.

Comment: Ok, I will, although this direction is obvious as boundedness is the same as the Lipschitz condition.

Comment: Yes, I agree that is "common knowledge" that between normed spaces a linear operator is bounded iff it is continuous, however who have asked the question is self-studying analysis, so more details are always a good thing :)